# how to perform calculation chr and dbl

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

let say I have this run this code

```
df_customer %>% 
  separate(DOB,sep = "-",into = c("D", "M","Y")) %>% 
  mutate(Age=2021)
```

then this dataframe comes out

```
ID      D   M   Y       G   C   Age
<int>   <   chr    >            <dbl>
268408  02  01  1970    M   4   2021
269696  07  01  1970    F   8   2021
268159  08  01  1970    F   8   2021
270181  10  01  1970    F   2   2021
268073  11  01  1970    M   1   2021
273216  15  01  1970    F   5   2021
266929  15  01  1970    M   8   2021
275152  16  01  1970    M   4   2021
275034  18  01  1970    F   4   2021
273966  21  01  1970    M   8   2021
```

then, I want to change that list of mutate column
how can I calculate something like 2021-"Y" column?
2021 is dbl and Y is chr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `convert = TRUE` in `separate` should give you numeric values. You can also use `as.numeric` to convert character to numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_customer %>% 
  separate(DOB,sep = "-",into = c("D", "M","Y"), convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Age=2021 - as.numeric(Y))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `base R`

```
transform(cbind(df_customer, read.table(text = df_customer$DOB, sep = "-", 
             column.names = c("D", "M", "Y"))), Age = 2021- Y)
```